# Scrapy spider connection reset by peer

Tags: python, web-crawler, screen-scraping, scrapy

I wrote a spider that crawls content and images from pages that are provided by a csv document. But in some cases python presents me with a "connection reset by peer" and this prevents my spider from spidering the other pages.

I'm fairly new to python and i was wondering how i can ignore or retry requests that receive this message, so it won't affect spidering.

This is my class:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector, Selector
from wearus.items import ProductItem
import re
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.http import Request

import urllib, csv


class dummySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dummy"
    domain = "dummy.com"

    parsed_hostnames = set()
    feed_url = "http://url.to/file.csv"
    start_urls = []
    allowed_domains = ['dummy.com' , domain]
    url_col_nr = 12

    handle_httpstatus_list = [404, 503]
    failed_urls = []

    stats = None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    # @classmethod
    # def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    #     return cls(crawler.stats)

    def start_requests(self):
      data = urllib.urlopen(self.feed_url)
      reader = csv.reader(data)

      log.msg("{0} items in csv file".format(len(list(csv.reader(urllib.urlopen(self.feed_url))))), level=log.INFO)

      next(reader)
      for row in reader:
          url = row[self.url_col_nr].strip()
          row_id = row[0].strip()

          # filter url
          match = re.search('\[\[(.*?)\/', url)

          if(match.group(1)):
            url = "http://" + self.domain + "/" + match.group(1)

          if (url.strip() != ""):
              item = ProductItem()
              item['prod_id'] = row_id
              request = self.make_requests_from_url(url)
              request.meta['item'] = item
              yield request



    def parse(self, response):
        print response

        if self.stats is None:
            self.stats = self.crawler.stats

        if response.status in self.handle_httpstatus_list:
            self.stats.inc_value('failed_url_count')
            self.failed_urls.append(response.url)
            # print response.url
            return

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sel = Selector(response)
        i = response.meta['item']
        name =  hxs.select('//h1[@class="product-detail-product-options"]/text()').extract()
        if (len(name) > 0): i['name'] = name[0]

        cats = sel.css('ul.zzg-breadcrumb>li a::text').extract()

        def cat_replace(item):
              return item.replace(' >', '')


        def cat_filter(item):
              return  item != 'Ana Sayfa'

        i['category'] = map(cat_replace, cats)
        i['category'] = filter(cat_filter, i['category'])

        i['url'] = response.url
        color = sel.css('.product-detail-box > table tr:first-child > td:first-child::text').extract()
        if (len(color) > 0): i['color'] = color[0]

        i['image_urls'] = sel.css('.product-detail-product-image a img::attr(src)').extract()


        return i

    def parse_error(self,failure):
        #print 'Error encontrado'

        # self.processed_urls = self.processed_urls +1
        # self.url_error = self.url_error + 1

        yield Request(self.start_urls.next(),callback=self.parse,errback=self.parse_error)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        if self.stats:
            self.stats.set_value('failed_urls', ','.join(spider.failed_urls))
```

and this it the error message:

```
ERROR: Obtaining request from start requests
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1192, in run
      self.mainLoop()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1201, in mainLoop
      self.runUntilCurrent()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
      call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/utils/reactor.py", line 41, in __call__
      return self._func(*self._a, **self._kw)
  --- <exception caught here> ---
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 111, in _next_request
      request = next(slot.start_requests)
    File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/dummy/spiders/dummy.py", line 42, in start_requests

    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 530, in next
      line = self.readline()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 430, in readline
      data = recv(1)
  socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: You are using `urllib.urlopen` bypassing the scrapy downloader. But that's not wrong, and the error is unrelated to scrapy. Try `scrapy shell http://url.to/file.csv` to see if it can be downloaded by scrapy. Also you can try `curl http://url.to/file.csv`, if none of those work, then you may have connectivity issues in either your side or server side.

Comment: Downloading the csv works just fine. Te problem is scrapping the pages. In some cases it works just fine and sometimes the connection got's reset during the crawling